# How to print cookie expiry date as shown in browser storage in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to print the cookie attributes i.e., name, value, domain, expires etc. as seen in the browser application storage.

I tried the following patch:

```
def testcase_03(self,test_setup):
    self.driver.get("https://lifesciences.cactusglobal.com/")
    print("Page title: " + self.driver.title)

    wanted_cookie=self.driver.get_cookie('__ivc')
    print(wanted_cookie)
```

The output is as below:

```
Page title: High-Impact Scientific Communication Solutions | Cactus Life Sciences
{'domain': '.cactusglobal.com', 'expiry': 1684985602, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '__ivc', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'a99fe4ba-7ff5-400f-90f9-422313b1c3c3'}
```

Now the expiry as seen in the chrome application storage is comprehensible `2023-05-25T12:16:44.000Z`

[image]

Is there anyway to print the values as displayed in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have already got the response and need to do the 3 things:

**1) Parse JSON response.**

```
//Convert response to proper JSON after replacing single quotes with double
wanted_cookie = wanted_cookie.replace("'", "\"")
//Load Json
wanted_cookie= json.loads(wanted_cookie)
```

**2) Extract expiry key value from the JSON.**

```
expiry = wanted_cookie["expiry"]
print(expiry)
```

**3) Format the date-time as per your requirements.**

```
convertedDT = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z', time.localtime(expiry))
 print(convertedDT)
```

**Complete Code:**

```
def testcase_03(self,test_setup):
    self.driver.get("https://lifesciences.cactusglobal.com/")
    print("Page title: " + self.driver.title)
    wanted_cookie=self.driver.get_cookie('__ivc')
    print(wanted_cookie)
    wanted_cookie = wanted_cookie.replace("'", "\"")
    wanted_cookie= json.loads(wanted_cookie)
    expiry = wanted_cookie["expiry"]
    print(expiry)
    convertedDT = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z', time.localtime(expiry))
    print(convertedDT)
```

***Note: Please Format expiryKey as per your requirement as shown in step 3.***